# How can I make "Windows Metafile" my default paste special option in Word 2007?

Tags: ms-word, paste, word-2007, metafile

I am doing a lot of copying from Visio to Word 2007. I have found that Windows Metafile is the most space efficient choice of the Paste Special options available. How can I make "Windows Metafile" my default paste special option in Word?

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for this but MicroSoft knows that nobody needs this and so it seems not to be possible. If you dare to disagree with the wisdom of Microsoft, you have the option of a workaround - like I did ...

Create a macro (obviously you find the macros in the View and not the Developer ribbon ...):

```
Sub PasteSpecialMetafile()
    Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End Sub
```

And then assign a special shortcut (simply and intuitively via File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Keyboard Shortcuts: Customize) to the macros. 
There might be a command which directly opens the PasteSpecial dialog ... but this is well hidden.

The macro works only, if the clipboard content can be converted to a metafile (and you get an error when the clipboard contains text). So there is room for improvement :)

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, default shortcut for the PasteSpecial is Ctrl+Alt+V. Full list of MS Word shortcuts is available in the Word Help, here is the [direct link](http://support.office.microsoft.com/client/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-9a2e0234-e682-49ff-a4aa-999f07b51bf3) for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers. They were very useful.
It worked in Word 2003 as well :).

I found another way. After you do all the clicks to do the paste special\picture(metafile) and paste your first picture, copy the next one (from excel or any other place) then go to Word and press Ctrl+Y to repeat the previous command.
Don't do anything else after you do the paste special in Word, the final action needs to be the paste special\picture.